# Mandating belief in an unsupported empirical claim under UK employment law

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, discrimination

Is the following scenario proscribed by UK law:

- An employer mandates that all employees complete an online learning activity. This includes an educational document followed by a multiple choice quiz with a mandatory 7/10 pass rate.
- For one of the questions, the acceptable answer implies an empirical claim. For example, "What is a benefit of having employee demographics that more closely resemble the demographics of wider society?" and the acceptable answer (among five choices) being "We can provide better customer service" (the empirical claim implied here is: businesses whose employee demographics more closely resemble wider society provide a better customer service).
- They provide no evidence to support this claim, in the educational document or elsewhere, either through their own research or with reference to published studies.
- An employee refuses to complete the quiz after requesting evidence for the aforementioned claim and being given none. The employee says they do not believe the claim to be true without evidence, that therefore they cannot provide the acceptable answer in good faith, and hence that this means they effectively have a 7/9 pass rate (if, say, they omit the problematic question).
- The employer pursues disciplinary action against the employee.

In particular, can the employee in the above scenario claim to be the victim of discrimination?

Does this come down to whether agreeing or not with an empirical claim without evidence constitutes "philosophical belief" under the Equality Act 2010?

Comment: If you get get that question “wrong” can you still get 7/10?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Yes, the employee would need to answer 7 of the remaining 9 questions correctly.

Comment: A wild guess - is the actual case about a diverse workforce improving a company rather than lots of consultants? It might make a difference in the answers.

Comment: Thanks George. It may be so, and I think you are probably right about deviating too much from the actual case - I will try to come up with a better example.

Comment: Have you considered that an employee may be required to **lie** to customers by company policy: "A pleasure to do business with you. I hope to see you again." Regardless of what the employee thinks about that particular customer. Being required to memorize and repeat ten out of ten answers should be a much lesser blemish on their soul.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Edited accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: @o.m. That's an interesting point, it sounds like you may have the germ of an answer there - are you able to develop it as an answer? Can you reference anything in the law or in precedent?

Comment: This question seems to be based on the requirement that providing the correct answer to a question requires actual belief that the answer is correct. How could such a requirement ever possibly be enforced? Is the quiz provided in a vacuum, or is the quiz given after the participant has viewed some sort of presentation or document which espouses this point? If that's the case, then the "correct" answer is the answer that matches the information provided in the presentation, regardless of whether you actually believe the presentation is correct.

Comment: @GeorgeDorn, I wouldn't presume to answer about UK law.

Comment: @barbecue The quiz is given at the end of a document. Indeed, to me it would be quite clear that if the information was in said document, it would be fair to require the employee to answer in the expected way. In my example, I say "They provide no evidence to support [the] claim" - take this to mean that the required information is not in the document. As to the requirement that "providing the correct answer to a question requires actual belief that the answer is correct", this is why I said the employee cannot "answer in good faith". The answer is not consistent with their (lack of) belief.

Comment: @GeorgeDorn Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you were saying there were no third-party references or research cited in the document, not that it was never mentioned in the document.

Comment: I’d expect the philosophical belief claim to be quite weak under Grainger Plc v Nicholson. Perhaps more promising could be a discrimination claim in case one had a (ideally medically diagnosed) psychiatric condition which would cause one to feel disproportionate distress at the notion of being made to tell what one knows to be a lie. I’m not aware of any directly relevant precedent but it’s just a creative synthesis of the various elements of the law. It might well be a stretch dueTo aspects I’m not thinking of but it would probably be stronger than the philosophical belief angle.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly not.  The closest case I can think of is [Conisbee v Crossley Farms](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunal-decisions/mr-g-conisbee-v-crossley-farms-ltd-and-others-3335357-2018) in which is was decided that vegetarian was not capable of satisfying the requirements and definition of being a philosophical belief as protected under the Equality Act.  It would seem that the belief that "businesses that hire more consultants achieve better performance" is a much weaker belief than vegetarian, and so would be expected to not be given such protection.

Comment: Thanks for that. What do you mean by "weaker belief", and how is that relevant to the answer?

Comment: Also, is [Casamitjana Costa v League Against Cruel Sports](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5e68c368d3bf7f269b07ef95/Mr_J_Casamitjana_Costa_v_League_Against_Cruel_Sports-3331129-2018-FMH_Judgment.pdf), see also [this](https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/newsroom/ethical-veganism/), in which it was decided veganism does count as a protected philosophical belief, significant here? Or is that assessment incorrect?

Comment: An interesting point in Conisbee v Crossley farms is respondents' submission 25, in which the solicitor for the respondents included "A philosophical belief may be based on science" as being from the guidance on the definition of philosophical belief. Any thoughts?

Comment: I should have mentioned: I have edited the question so that "businesses that hire more consultants achieve better performance" is no longer the belief at issue. I'm not sure if it changes the substance of your answer, but it may do: the new belief in my question is arguably less "weak".